# how to disable remove option while uploading file in ng-zorro's nz-upload?

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I am using ngzorro's nz-upload component to upload pdf files. But i have one issue that when the user removes the file while still upload , it causes problems in my array where i store responses.
Is there a way to disable the remove option while still uploading ? or another work-around maybe ?

Comment: would you mind sharing some of your code? people will offer better help if you do so

Comment: not useful without code!

Answer (score 2):

You need to make 'showRemoveIcon=false' to disable remove icon in nz-zorro upload.

```
<nz-upload
  nzAction="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"
  nzShowUploadList = "{showRemoveIcon?: false}"
  >
  <button nz-button><i nz-icon nzType="upload"></i><span>Click to Upload</span></button>
</nz-upload>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can disable remove option by setting showRemoveIcon : false

**HTML**

```
<nz-upload class="avatar-uploader"
  nzAction="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" nzName="avatar"
  nzListType="picture-card" [nzShowUploadList]="showUploadList"
  [nzBeforeUpload]="beforeUpload"  (nzChange)="handleChange($event)"
  >
```

**JS**

```
showUploadList = {
 showPreviewIcon: true,
showRemoveIcon: false,
};
```